# How to align items precisely in a table layout?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have problem to align items in table layout.
[image]

as you can see when the last item had more than one line, the next text going to the next line but it cant precisely with the text above.

this is the xml:

```
<TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Notes"
                    android:layout_column="1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_notes"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:maxLines="4"/>

            </TableRow>
```

I already tried to set the colon in new text view but its nothing.

so i tried to add the colon along with the setText in java,
This is the java class :

```
orderListViewHolder.txtDate.setText(": "+itemOrderList.get(position).getDate());
        orderListViewHolder.txtOrderNumber.setText(": "+itemOrderList.get(position).getOrderNumber());
        orderListViewHolder.txtCustomerName.setText(": "+itemOrderList.get(position).getCustomerName());
        orderListViewHolder.txtProductStatus.setText(": "+itemOrderList.get(position).getProductStatus());
        orderListViewHolder.txtNotes.setText(": "+itemOrderList.get(position).getNotes());
```

how can I align that items precisely?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your layout and it works fine if you insert a TextView with text `:` between the 2 TextViews:

```
        <TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Notes"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=":"
        android:layout_column="2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_notes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="4"/>

</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem, You should use any basic Linear Layout with horizontal orientation.

Please have a look

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Notes :"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp"
                tools:text="Motor Bekas Honda Supra X"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

But still if you looking for using table layout then please try below sample

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Notes :"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="Motor Bekas Honda Supra X ,Motor Bekas Honda Supra X,Motor Bekas Honda Supra X" />


    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Any xyz :"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="Motor Bekas Honda Supra" />


    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

Screenshots:

[image]